# Using jQuery, I tried to append each colour name from the same class for each different element with the sameclass name

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to append each colour name (from `background-colour` property) from the same class name cllaed `plano-1` for each element which also has the same class name (but different) called `cor-hex`, so I did not have to copy the colour for the elements, I let JavaScript does it. For example:

```
<tr>
 <td><div class="plano-1" style="background-color: #220642"></div></td>
 <td class="cor-hex"></td>
 <td class="cor-rgb"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><div class="plano-1" style="background-color: #1976D2"></div></td>
 <td class="cor-hex"></td>
 <td class="cor-rgb"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><div class="plano-1" style="background-color: #1565C0"></div></td>
 <td class="cor-hex"></td>
 <td class="cor-rgb"></td>
</tr>
```

Here is the small and first alternative code, using `each` and `css` of jQuery:

```
$(function () 
{
    $('.cor-hex').each(function () 
    {
        var hexad = $(".plano-1").css('background-color');  

        hexad = hexad.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
        function hex(x) {return ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2);}
        hexad = "#" + hex(hexad[1]) + hex(hexad[2]) + hex(hexad[3]);

        $('.cor-hex').append(""+hexad);
    })
});
```

But it duplicated three times the same first colour name in three elements.

If I changed `each` to `filter`, it would almost work, but the three elements received the same colour name.

So I tried to use an ES6 array, modifying:

```
const colours =
{
    "cor-hex-1": "plano-1.cor-1",
    "cor-hex-2": "plano-1.cor-2",
    "cor-hex-3": "plano-1.cor-3"
};

var allColours = Object.keys(colours);
allColours.forEach(colour => $(colour).css('background-color'));
$(colour).append(""+colour);
```

I also modified the HTML:

```
<tr>
 <td><div class="plano-1 cor-1" style="background-color: #220642"></div></td>
 <td class="cor-hex-1"></td>
 <td class="cor-rgb"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><div class="plano-1 cor-2" style="background-color: #1976D2"></div></td>
 <td class="cor-hex-2"></td>
 <td class="cor-rgb"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><div class="plano-1 cor-3" style="background-color: #1565C0"></div></td>
 <td class="cor-hex-3"></td>
 <td class="cor-rgb"></td>
</tr>
```

It did not work either.

I simplified the code and tried to use `each` and switching from `.cor` to `.plano-1`:

```
var colours_hex = $('.cor-hex');

$('.plano-1').css("background-color").each(function (i) 
{
    colours_hex.eq(i).append($(""+this));
});
```

Comment: Do you want to apply the color from the _first_ `.plano-1` to _all_ `. cor-hex` elements across the whole document - or maybe rather only just to those within the same table row …?

Comment: Just tot hose within, somebodu gave the answers, @CBroe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed 2 lines:

```
var hexad = $(".plano-1").css('background-color'); 
$('.cor-hex').append("" + hexad);
```

to:

```
var hexad = $(this).closest('tr').find(".plano-1").css('background-color');
$(this).append("" + hexad);
```

Problem was that when you select let say `$(".plano-1")` it had no direct relation to the `$('.cor-hex')` you used in `.each()`

**Demo**

```js
$(function() {
  $('.cor-hex').each(function() {
    var hexad = $(this).closest('tr').find(".plano-1").css('background-color');

    hexad = hexad.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);

    function hex(x) {
      return ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    }
    hexad = "#" + hex(hexad[1]) + hex(hexad[2]) + hex(hexad[3]);

    $(this).append("" + hexad);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <div class="plano-1" style="background-color: #220642"></div>
  </td>
  <td class="cor-hex"></td>
  <td class="cor-rgb"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <div class="plano-1" style="background-color: #1976D2"></div>
  </td>
  <td class="cor-hex"></td>
  <td class="cor-rgb"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <div class="plano-1" style="background-color: #1565C0"></div>
  </td>
  <td class="cor-hex"></td>
  <td class="cor-rgb"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the specific instance and use that instance to look for the associated element in same row to set the text

```js
function hex(x) {
  return ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2);
}

$('.plano-1').each(function() {
  // get style value from current instance
  var hexad = $(this).css('background-color');
  hexad = hexad.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
  hexad = "#" + hex(hexad[1]) + hex(hexad[2]) + hex(hexad[3]);
  // set text of element in same row
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.cor-hex').text(hexad)

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="plano-1" style="background-color: #220642"></div>
    </td>
    <td class="cor-hex"></td>
    <td class="cor-rgb"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="plano-1" style="background-color: #1976D2"></div>
    </td>
    <td class="cor-hex"></td>
    <td class="cor-rgb"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="plano-1" style="background-color: #1565C0"></div>
    </td>
    <td class="cor-hex"></td>
    <td class="cor-rgb"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can `.text` of `.css` append the value of variable name? For example, `<td class="color-variable"></td>` will become `<td class="color-variable">var(--base)</td>`.